# Resizing a Layout

Tags: android, view, resize

I have two view in a container like this.

```
[ContainerView    
[view 1 (RelativeLayout)]    
[view 2 (RelativeLayout)]    
(Relative Layout)]
```

and id like to hide view1 whenever a certain variable is not given. i cant seem to find a solution to

1. hide view1 completely
2. resive view2 to fill the entire ContainerView

Now i know this question has been asked a billion times, but all the solutions simply dont work for me...

Here are parts of the code:

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eeeeee"
android:id="@+id/mainview">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/header">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/upperview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lowerview"
    android:layout_above="@+id/header">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/vanisherView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/erklareung"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:id="@+id/lowerview"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom">
</RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:background="#009688"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and what i tried sofar is

1. `upperview.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    lowerview.getLayoutParams().height = 900;
    mainview.invalidate()`
2. same with requestLayout
3. creating a new RelativeLayout for the lower layout with static sizes
4. `upperview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           lowerview.getLayoutParams().height = 900;`

Cheers

Jacobus

Comment: VIew1.setVisiblity(VISIBLE.GONE)

Comment: @VarunKumar getLayoutParams().height = 0/900, and similar Layout changes, basically the only solution that is getting proposed for other questions

Comment: Post your code. Edit the question above and post your code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what you have already tried in order to achieve this. For your reference, I am posting a sample code which is used to achieve the same output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Text Field in View 1" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlView1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Text Field in View 2" />
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please note that, you have to use rlView1.setVisiblity(View.GONE) in order to make rlView2 the same size as of parent.

Comment: i just posted my xml. i am sorry for that inconvenience :D i need the lower view to be of static size from the begining

Comment: i just tried your solution it appears to not work either. i made rlView of static size, and did the layout_below=rlView1. i then call setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), but it only hides it, and the other views size doesnt change. EDIT View.GONE does the trick... i guess im just retarded

Comment: Oh yes my mistake, instead of VISIBLE.GONE it should be View.GONE